# What is the meaning of `lt` in `[if lt IE 9]`

Tags: html, css, conditional-comments

What is the meaning of `lt` in the following script?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Less/Lower Than

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That's an Internet Explorer [conditional comment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx), which reads out "if using Internet Explorer **less than** version 9 (IE8 and lower), do this...".

When the conditional passes, [HTML5Shiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)#HTML5_Shiv) is run in the browser.

> HTML5Shiv is a JavaScript workaround, created by Sjoerd Visscher, to enable styling of HTML5 elements in versions of Internet Explorer prior to version 9, which do not allow unknown elements to be styled without JavaScript.

Comment: If somebody is interested in a bit of history, check out Paul Irish's [The Story of the HTML5 Shiv](https://www.paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/)

Comment: Someone made a video about this Q and A: https://youtu.be/O_Eha0ReFsE ... at least it mentions the original authors and the license, but ... :rolling-my-eyes:

Answer (score 9):

It means the same as "less than". A list of alternative comparison operators you might encounter follows:

- lt < (less than)
- gt > (greater than)
- eq ==  (equal to)
- ne != (not equal to)
- gte >= (greater than or equal to)
- lte <= (less than or equal to)

(fixed less/greater or equal operators)

Comment: It is `lte` and `gte` for less/greater or equal than.

Comment: It depends; like if you inspect [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), you'll see some things like `<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->`, etc..